# Take screenshots on focus change

Tags: focus, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am developing a chrome extension and I have a situation where I have two input fields(textbox). Once the focus changes from the first textbox to the second textbox, I want to start taking screenshots whenever a mouse-click event occurs.

My first question is how do I get alerted whenever focus change takes place ?

This is my content script for taking screenshots which I am going to inject into a website. Unfortunately it's not working at the moment.

content_script.js

```
document.onclick=function() {
  {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){

  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(win.id, function(imgUrl) {
     var screenshotUrl = imgUrl;
console.log(screenshotUrl);
});
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onblur.html

```
Code:
Enter email address <INPUT TYPE="text" VALUE="" NAME="userEmail" onBlur=addCheck()>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function addCheck() {
 alert("Please check your email details are correct before submitting")
}

</script>
```

Comment: If you haven't looked into the screenshot part here is a url with one possible solution: http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/10/14/how-snapabug-works/

Comment: so, for me its like a random page, for example a Google sign-in page. How can I do this on that?

Comment: Well, using your content script. It is a pretty basic part of creating an extension.

Comment: Hmmm. So what you really want is to trigger screenshots anytime the page is clicked anywhere? Really? Assuming that is not what you want --- what you need to do is use js to find the elements you are interested in and attach an onblur event handler to them.

Comment: that is just a test; I still have to make it suit my needs. But even the test is not working.

Comment: Are you new to both javascript and chrome extensions?